# How Do I Check if an XML File Has any nodes, other than the root?

Tags: xslt, xpath

With XSLT, I am processing an xml file which might not have any nodes, other than the root. I want to output a special message on the html page for this case. I am using a for-each element to process the xml file. How do I check if the xml file has any actual nodes in it?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation and several XPath expressions that select what you may be wanting. :)

Answer (score 4):

> How Do I Check if an XML File Has No
>   Nodes?

**By definition, any well-formed XML document contains at least a top element.**

Therefore, any XML document contains some nodes -- there can't be an XML document that has no nodes.

I understand this question as asking: "*How to determine that the top element of an XML document has no descendents?"*

**This is in fact an XPath question**. This XPath expression:

```
/*[not(node())]
```

is `true()` exactly when the top element of the document has no child nodes (elements, text-nodes, processing instructions or comments).

**The top element can still have attributes and it always has namespace nodes**, but these two kinds of nodes are not considered to be exactly "children".

```
/*[not(node()) and not(@*)]
```

is `true()` exactly when the top element has no child nodes and no attributes.

```
/*[not(*)]
```

is `true()` exactly when the top element has no child element nodes (but it still can have text-node children, processing-instruction children and comment-nodes children).

Comment: +1 Right answer. As for clarification: OP wrote *I am processing an xml file which might not have any nodes, other than the root*.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks. However, the root (node) is != the top element. Having the right terminology is important.